# Recover Secure Store Pass Phrase

Tags: secure-store, password

When you create a new "Secure Store Service App" you will also create "Generate New Key" and it requires you to input Pass Phrase.

We totally forgot the password and now in trouble because I need to restore this database to dev.

Is there a powershell or code that can help me retrieve this pass phrase?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible.  SharePoint uses the pass phrase to generate an encryption key, it doesn't actually store it.